# Accessing value of param in xsl

Tags: xslt

I am trying to get the value of the parameter of template named as is Round from the following code but it returns me the blank, can anybody tell me that how to get value of parameter in template

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//solution">
            <xsl:with-param name="isRound">N</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:apply-templates>

  <xsl:template match="solution">
    <xsl:param name="isRound" />
    <test>
      <xsl:value-of select="$isRound"/>
    </test>
  </xsl:template>
```

The Output of this is:

```
<test></test>
```

Comment: Could you show us more of your XSLT? At least all of the template that contains that `xsl:apply-templates`, and a few more levels up the hierarchy as well? Perhaps the `apply-templates` you have there isn't getting used and `solution` is being matched on its own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this works. I try it as following. Adding other necessary things such as stylesheet root element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//solution">
            <xsl:with-param name="isRound">N</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="solution">
        <xsl:param name="isRound" />
            <test>
                <xsl:value-of select="$isRound"/>
            </test>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input for example.

```
<root>
    <solution/>
</root>
```

Result

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test>N</test>
```